# Does Primefaces-Mobile have a Schedule component?

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I am intending to use primefaces-mobile to build a mobile web application for my org. I have used the schedule component which is available in primefaces framework for web applications. But is there a similar Schedule Component in primefaces mobile ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `calendar` component? See [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/calendar.xhtml) for mobile example. There are also various ajax events available to open a dialog similar to schedule.

Comment: Can this calendar component show events over it, like how a schedule component shows. ?

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is not possible. Have you tried using the `<p:schedule>` component  on a mobile device? Although not all components are officially supported by the mobile render kit they might work anyway.

Comment: You might better take a look to pf-mobile components and decide if the available components will be enough for you, before you start rewriting a separate mobile app. You might also consider upgrading your existing web app to the latest version, and apply the responsive design features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"But is there a similar Schedule Component in primefaces mobile ?"*

No, as can be seen by just examining the showcases

> *"Can this calendar component show events over it, like how a schedule component shows. ?"*

No, as can be seen by lack of examples in the showcase of such specific fumctionality